# Getting NoClassDefFoundError while invoking external JAR in maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a maven based project where I have to invoke an external jar **(say country.jar)**

I added this jar on **src/lib** folder and did below setting in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>country-stubs</groupId>
     <artifactId>country-stubs</artifactId>
     <scope>system</scope>
     <version>1.0</version>
     <systemPath>${basedir}\src\lib\country.jar</systemPath>
  </dependency>
```

While Running my application I am getting error 
***java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fsg/bpo/webservices/countWebService***

Location(**com/fsg/bpo/webservices/countWebService**) is referring to the class present under country JAR

Do I need to add few more settings to configure external JAR in maven ?

Comment: Maybe it could be a silly question but, can you check if inside on the jar is the file com/fsg/bpo/webservices/countWebService.class ???, you can open the jar with your favorite compress tool (like 7zip)

Comment: I would use `/` as a dir separator in POMs, even on Windows - though I can't promise that's the cause of this issue.

Comment: Also note that the `system` scope is deprecated. Maybe you should use `provided`.

Comment: Are you running your application as war. If so can you check whether the jar is getting bundled or not

Answer (score 0):

If you are using scope system you are saying it is a provided jar later on. I would use runtime maybe.  [Have a look at maven scopes](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html)

Comment: I would check if the jar you say(country.jar) is inside the build project whatever itis (War or JAR). Is it there?

Comment: If you are building a JAR  you have to use maven-assembly-plugin to add dependencies in the jar. They are not added by default

Answer (score 0):

If it is web application then your jar won't get bundled inside your war file. Then you will get this issue. you can directly copy this country.jar to your WEB-INF lib folder and use that system path.

Answer (score 0):

1st u need to add ur external jar to ur local maven directory..
using below command on cmd..

mvn install:install-file -DgroupId= -DartifactId=aes-decryption -Dversion=1.0.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=./target/aes-decryption-1.0.0.jar -DgeneratePom=true